# Intermediate Op Amp Practice and Material

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, analog

I have an interview coming up where I will likely be tested on the basics of ideal op amps.  I am confident in my fundamentals, such as solving the typical basic configs (inverting, non inv, summer, difference, integrator, etc) as well as cascaded arrangements.  However, I would like to dig into the next level. My research so far makes it seem like there is not a lot that builds off of these basics but rather, they go immediately deep into the weeds. It seems I havent gathered the intermediate skills as I am largely unable to solve the more challenging circuits.

Would anyone out there have some recommendations, practice problems, or any other resources to help me take my op amp fundamentals to the next level?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I doubt anyone would get interviewed on "advanced opamp circuits" specifically, but maybe on "advanced analog electronics"; most likely from the application area the company is operating in. So rather than obsessing about opamps, which really are but a tiny amount of electronics, maybe focus on the bigger picture, figure out what the team does that you apply for, and understand the electronics needed there. E.g. if they build optical transmitters, then learn about that. If they build audio amplifiers, that. Radios: that, and so on.

Comment: Generally, I'd like to appeal to your engineering pride: you're an engineer. You should always strive to get a job where you *solve problems* rather than *finish assignments* on your very specific area of expertise that a real engineer needs to prepare for you. Also, the first typically pays way, way better. So, try to understand what they want you to do in the future and learn about that. I swear that noone cares about "general example circuit knowledge" beyond the basics of a field (there, very much); companies need independent people, not working machines that can be replaced by algorithms.

Comment: Marcus,  thank you for the insight.  I agree, there is no sense in solidifying just one skill, but in sake of that greater picture, I recognize that my op amp analysis (among other skills) seems to be stuck at the basics.  I would like to break past that barrier because as I mentioned, the harder practice problems that I can find are not remotely easy for me to solve. I intend to do this for every developing skill I come across.

Comment: Awesome! That means you've identified the skill you want to hone: how to break down complex, harder practical problems into smaller one. Often, a good book can get help started with that. "The Art of Electronics" is one such book that many engineers swear by – it should have a very good time spent reading vs knowledge gained (also: interviewer impressed) tradeoff :)

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation Marcus! I’ve been meaning to get this book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been reading passages from ADI's OP AMP Handbook and it's really helped me with designing and analyzing precision op amp circuits.

https://www.analog.com/en/education/education-library/op-amp-applications-handbook.html

It's all free online.  The parts about noise analysis are very practical and applicable to my current work.

Comment: Ah! This looks excellent! Thanks a bunch!

Comment: No problem. The analog guru at my work calls it his bible!